# Http listener only works with POST not GET

Tags: java, http, post, get

I have a simple program either a server or client not sure which end it is. I open a port and accept messages on it. this works but it crashed last night when I revived a message via GET not POST. As you may have noticed I am very new to networking.

I am getting the transmission ok (the socket stuff) but i cant read the message.

this is the code i currently use.

```
//read HTTp header until the message size comes in
            for(int eight = 0; eight < 8; eight++)
            {
                message = in.readLine();
                LOGGER.fatal(eight);
                LOGGER.fatal(message);

                if(message.contains("Content-Length"))
                {
                    try {

                        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
                        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(message);
                        while (matcher.find()) {
                            sizeInt = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group());
                                               }
                        }

                    catch (Exception e) 
                        {
                            LOGGER.fatal("size not found on header line", e);
                            //System.exit(-1);
                        }                   
                }
            }

            LOGGER.fatal(sizeInt);

            LOGGER.fatal("---------------------------");

            char[] buffer =new char[sizeInt];

            //skip blank line between header and message
            message = in.readLine();

            //read message
            int fullRead = 0;
            int thisRead = 0;
            do
            {
                thisRead = in.read(buffer, fullRead, sizeInt - fullRead);   
                LOGGER.info(fullRead + " of " + sizeInt + " bytes of message read");
                fullRead += thisRead;

            }while(fullRead != sizeInt);
```

The problem iv'e got is that the GET method does not seen to have  the size of the message in bytes and without that I don't know how the read the message without it hanging.

I'm using java.

Can anyone suggest how I can edit this code to understand a GET message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A GET request doesn't *have* any content - there's nothing to read. Any data has to be in the headers / URL.

Comment: its a message sent between two computers on a network, there is no user interface stuff, the software opens a port and sends the message which is why im getting confused as everyone keeps going on about URL

Comment: @Skeith: If it's an HTTP request, there's a URL involved. URLs are independent of user interfaces.

Comment: @Skeith: It'll be one of the first lines you read. You should really read up on HTTP if you're trying to implement it...

Comment: I have tried looking but everything I can find goes on about browsers and that not what I need. If you can recommend a source that relates to what I'm doing I would be happy to read it.

Comment: @Skeith: You could start with the RFC: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html

Comment: @Jon Skeet this is the first line I read: GET / HTTP/1.1. second line: Accept: image/gif, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg, image/pjpeg, application/x-shockwave-flash, application/x-ms-application, application/x-ms-xbap, application/vnd.ms-xpsdocument, application/xaml+xml, */*. third line:Accept-Language: en-gb. fourth line:User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.2; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729). fifth line: Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate. sixth line: Host: (ip address removed). seventy line: Connection: Keep-Alive.

Comment: @Jon Skeet Where in that does it tell me how to get a 3587 byte XML message. I have looked but I cannot find anything in that header that points to or contains the expected message.

Comment: @Skeith: If you want an XML message, I wouldn't expect that to be part of a URL. That should really be in a POST request. **GET requests don't have bodies**

Comment: @Jon Skeet I know all of this, that's why my program was written to receive POST messages and I did not consider GET messages but the other company has decided to use GET exclusively to send all there commands. So I need to know how can I receive XML messages through GET.

Comment: @Skeith: You claim you "know all of this", but you're still asking questions which don't make much sense. If this other company is including data in their GET request then it should *either* be in the URL *or* in the headers. Look at the request to see which it is. Either way it's inappropriate, frankly.

Comment: @Jon Skeet I know it does not make sense, but the comment I posted is what I receive. I have 12 messages all the same and from what your telling me there is no message in them. I know I should be using post but its difficult to tell international companies that there doing it wrong.

Comment: @Skeith: So have you looked at the request? Maybe they *are* including a body in a GET request, which they really shouldn't be...

Comment: @Jon Skeet I don't know what you are meaning when you say request. My program logs all the headers of a message which I have shown you and then reads the body which is when it crashes for obvious reasons.

Comment: @Skeith: If you don't know what I mean by "request" then you *really, really* need to start learning about HTTP from scratch.

Comment: @Jon Skeet there program sends mine messages on a timed basis. I never send him anything except a confirmation, there are no requests for information if that's what you mean.

Comment: @Skeith: Your program is acting as a server. The client is sending you requests. I certainly *hope* you're serving a response from that request, even if it's just a simple 200. Again, please learn about HTTP either from a tutorial or the RFC.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to implement an HTTP server (it's not a client, because you want to read HTTP request, not make them). If you're "very new to networking", I wouldn't recommend it. Anyway, if you really want to build your own HTTP server there are examples on the Web, for instance [this one](http://fragments.turtlemeat.com/javawebserver.php). Another approach, if you need an HTTP server in your application is to use [`com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/index.html) (the link include a minimal example).

Answer (score 0):

HTTP GET does not have any content, and therefor does not have a content-length. Also, a HTTP POST does not necessarily need to specify Content-Length in HTTP/1.1: [HTTP Message Length](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.4)

Comment: That was kind of my point. I wanted to know how to read the content of the GET message as it does not show in the hearer and there is no body.

Comment: @Skeith: "Content of the GET message" is a bit of an oxymoron (as a lot of people have pointed out). A GET request only has the first line (url and HTTP version) and subsequent headers in the lines following. That's it. Also, Content-Length in POST is technically a MIME header if used to signify length of content (sans headers).

Comment: @pap what word would you use to refer to the XML that I am being sent then? There has to be some kind of "content" otherwise all GET messages would be empty and contain no data.

Comment: @Skeith: Indeed, they don't have any body. They just have the URL and the headers. That's it.